# Make `define` evaluate its first argument in Racket

Tags: racket

In some dialects of LISP, there is a distinction between `SET` and `SETQ`, the first one evaluates its first argument so that you need to use the `(SET (QUOTE …) …)` syntax.

Since in Racket, quoting is not needed in definitions, `define` behaves as `SETQ`.
Is there a Racket function that behaves like `SET`? If no, how to write one?

I tried `(define (SET a b) (define (eval a) b) b)` but it does not seem to work when providing it to an other language with `(provide SET)`.

Comment: One thing important in Racket is that variable bindings are determined at compile-time, not run-time, so `define` variables cannot be "evaluated" at run-time. However, it can be evaluated at compile-time with a macro. Can you clarify what you want this for?

Comment: I want this because I'm using Racket to build an educational language where I need a `SET` function

Answer (score 3):

Here's my quick attempt at this problem:

```
;; lib.rkt
#lang racket/base

(provide (rename-out [@set set]
                     [@#%top #%top]
                     [@set! set!]
                     [@define define]))
(require syntax/parse/define)

(define env (make-hash))

(define (set x v stx)
  (unless (hash-has-key? env x)
    (raise-syntax-error #f "undefined id" stx))
  (hash-set! env x v))

(define-simple-macro (@#%top . x)
  (hash-ref
   env
   'x
   (λ () (raise-syntax-error #f "unbound id" (quote-syntax x)))))

(define (@set x v)
  (set x v x))

(define-simple-macro (@set! x:id v)
  (set 'x v (quote-syntax x)))

(define-simple-macro (@define x:id v)
  (begin 
    (when (hash-has-key? env 'x)
      (raise-syntax-error #f "id already defined" (quote-syntax x)))
    (hash-set! env 'x v)))
```

```
#lang racket/base

(require "lib.rkt")

(define x 1)
(set (if #t 'x 'y) 2)
(add1 x) ; 3
(set! x 3)
(add1 x) ; 4
(add1 y) ; y: unbound id in: y
```

Note that this differs from original Racket in several ways. For example:

1. unbound ids are now reported at runtime instead of compile-time.
2. `set!` now won't work with `set!-transformer`.
3. `define` can't be used to define functions
4. `define` can't be used to shadow an identifier.

For (2) and (3), it's possible to get the original behavior back, but I don't want the answer to be too long, so I didn't include the full functionality. For now, I don't know how to solve (4).

Also note that you can only `set` identifiers defined via `define`. If you want to `set` identifiers defined via `lambda`, `let`, etc., you need to redefine these constructs too.

Comment: If I understand correctly, in your implementation a variable must be defined before the set and set! commands could be used?

Comment: Yes, that's how `set!` works in Racket. If you don't like that, then remove the check `(unless (hash-has-key? env x) ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it much less verbose and much simpler.

Since all arguments are evaluated, the `set` or let's say `define%` can be defined as a function!

```
(define (define% x y)
    (eval `(define ,x ,y)))
```

One can even define functions using `define%` when using old-style form using `lambda`.

```
(define 'ab (lambda (x y) (+ x y)))

(ab 3 5) ;; 7
```

It even behaves correctly in terms of scope

```
(define (foo x)
    (define% 'bar (lambda (x) (+ 1 x)))
    (bar (bar (bar x))))

foo
;; #<procedure:foo>
bar
; bar: undefined;
;  cannot reference undefined identifier
; [,bt for context]

(foo 3)
6

;; after first call however, bar is available in global environment
;; as pointed out by @AlexKnauf
bar 
;; #<procedure:bar>
```

Thus there are some scoping issues ...

```
(let ((x 0))                                                                                                                           
  (define% 'counter (lambda () (set! x (+ x 1)) x)))                                                                        
counter
;; #<procedure>
(counter)
;; 1
(counter)
;; 2
(counter)
;; 3
```

Comment: I think you should warn about some of the dangers of `eval`, it can be a trap for beginners who don't know yet when is and isn't a good situation to use it

Comment: no - this use of `eval` is safe. But sure, one should not use `eval` if one can avoid it. But in this particular case, `eval` is "good".

Comment: I call it "eval-over-macrocall". I discussed it here https://lisp-univ-etc.blogspot.com/2020/06/eval-spotted-in-wild.html with Vsevolod Dyomkin. In my view, `eval` used correctly is an asset.

Comment: I think it's unsafe in this particular case as well: The 3rd codeblock in your answer breaks in 2 situations: (a) it breaks when the definition of `foo` is put into a module (only works in the repl or larger eval), and (b) when in a repl, it breaks after `foo` is called: after a call to `(foo 10)`, `bar` is defined outside its scope

Comment: true ... after first cll of `(foo 1)`, `bar` is visible outside ...